# Activating Triggers on opportunity owner change

Tags: trigger

Is it possible to activate a trigger when the opportunity owner is changed? Please help

Answer (score 3):

Of course it is. Your trigger should fire on before update:

```
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (before update)
{
    for (Opportunity oppty : trigger.new)
    {
        if (oppty.OwnerId != trigger.oldMap.get(oppty.Id).OwnerId)
        {
            // Owner changed, do something
        }
    }
}
```

When using on update triggers you can always reference the new and the old values of the record.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, it did not activate the trigger

Comment: Sorry it worked. Since I had only 1 user it did not work